# BSOD in srv.sys when playing a movie from another computer across Windows network

Tags: bsod

Been at this problem for a few hours and struggling. When I watch a movie/tv/music from a laptop connected to this PC via a simple Windows Workgroup, it will occasionally BSOD with PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA. The media is located on a Lacie External HDD. It does not BSOD when on my local drive.

```
ntkrnlpa.exe    ntkrnlpa.exe+4939a  0x804d7000  0x806e5000  0x0020e000  0x4d00d46f  12/9/2010 11:06:55 PM   Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    NT Kernel & System  5.1.2600.6055 (xpsp_sp3_gdr.101209-1647)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe    

srv.sys srv.sys+3db83   0xa9163000  0xa91ba600  0x00057600  0x4d5d2009  2/17/2011 11:18:01 PM   Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Server driver   5.1.2600.6082 (xpsp_sp3_gdr.110217-1622)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\srv.sys
```

I've run various virus/malware scanners and all is fine. I assume it has SOMETHING to do with my external HDD.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, occasional BSODs are an indicator of a faulty system driver or RAM failure, or a combination of both.

So, update all your drivers and test your RAM with [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/).

However, external USB drivers are prone to power management complexities.
It might also have to do with that.